# Using Jquery $getJSON How do I dynamically create data for the [data] parameter after Url param?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have no problems getting the Json to work and parse the json return. I was just wondering how I could build a dynamic "whatever data is" and stick it into [data] to pass my parameters from there and not manually append them to the url.

From jquery website example:

```
$.getJSON("test.js", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(json){
     alert("JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name);
});
```

I thought I could build a string ( which doesn't make sense anyway ) and drop it inside the { }, but I obviously don't understand that part.

name: isn't a string and you can't put a variable in that part, so how would I dynamically put items into whatever [data] is.

UPDATE: Thanks for the answers. Would I be able to remove a parameter name from the object if I didn't find a valid value later on or would I need to destroy it and recreate it? I am using some select boxes to choose things and I may not have something selected so I wouldn't want to pass that parameter name/value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can build your object like this:

```
var someVar = someRandomString();
$.getJSON('test.js', (function() {
  var theData = {};
  theData[someVar] = someRandomValue();
  return theData;
})(), function(jsonStuffFromServer) {
  alert("JSON Data: " + jsonStuffFromServer.users[3].name);
});
```

Of course you don't have to build up the "data" object right there in an anonymous function; you can do it separately beforehand:

```
var theData = {};
theData[someVariableWithANameInIt] = someRandomValue();
$.getJSON(url, theData, function(jsonStuff) { ... });
```

Here's how you could build up such an object from a set of `<select>` elements on your page:

```
var theData = {};
$('#myForm select').filter(function() { return $(this).val() != ''; })
  .each(function() {
    theData[this.name] = $(this).val();
  });

$.getJSON(url, theData, function(jsonStuff) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am re-populating a select based on another selects chosen value, so I am fetching the correct options to populate based on certain parameters that can change dynamically across the form

Comment: @Pointy : By the way, that last "select each" code could really come in real handy for something else :)

Comment: Cool!  I think there's a better way to filter by using some magic in the "selector" itself (the '#myform select' part), but I'm not 100% sure how to do it and I haven't had any coffee this morning :-)

Answer (score 7):

Create an object, then you can put any properties you like in it:

```
var data = new Object();
```

or:

```
var data = {};
```

You can use property syntax:

```
data.name = 'John';
data.time = '2pm';
```

or associate array syntax (which is useful if the parameter name is a keyword):

```
data['name'] = 'John';
data['time'] = '2pm';
```

You can of course use variables for the values, and even use variables to specify the parameter name:

```
var param = 'name';
var value = 'John';
data[param] = value;
```

Then you just use the data variable in the call:

```
$.getJSON("test.js", data, function(json){
   alert("JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name);
});
```

Comment: So I think I get it. Would I be able to remove a parameter name if I didn't find a valid value later on? I am using some select boxes to choose things and I may not have something selected so I wouldn't want to pass that parameter name/value.

Comment: You don't have to build the object in advance. Just build it up, `<select>` by `<select>`, and only put in it the ones with values.

Comment: What I mean though is when you pick the top select, you have to start over, so the lower selects are reset so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var myName = $("#nameField").val();
var myTime = $("#timeField").val();

$.getJSON("test.js", { 'name': myName, 'time': myTime}, function(json){
     alert("JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name);
});
```

Is that what you mean, or dynamic parameters as well as variables?

Answer (score 0):

The {} is a javascript [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals#Object_Literals) so name is a property of that object.

You can do something like this:

```
var data = {};
data.name = $("#input").val();
$.getJSON("test.js", data, function(json){
     alert("JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name);
});
```

Or something like this

```
var data = {
    name: $("#input").val(),
};
$.getJSON("test.js", data, function(json){
     alert("JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name);
});
```

Comment: I think he wants the parameter *names* to be computed at runtime.